# Is it allowed to ask if a certain measurement index is reliable?

Tags: support, specific-question

I'd like to ask about how valid HDI (Human development index) is. I mean, if what they use for making the index, is more and less valid (obviously there can be errors, but at least it uses a good methodology to get the data and it's almost never some made up number that has been agreed in some way).

Would such a type of question be allowed in this site?

Comment: Do you have a notable claim saying it is or isn't reliable?

Answer (score 3):

The question "Is [this measure] valid?" would likely be closed for being unclear.

Are you referring to validity in the sense of repeatability and inter-rater reliability? Or some other aspect of [test validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_validity)? Or something else?

This is hard enough with the hundreds of common measures: GDP, resting pulse rate, air temperature, LSAT score. What would it mean to say if they are "valid" or not?

But it is especially hard for something like HDI which is an algorithm that fundamentally encodes a group's political opinion. [Not necessarily party-political, but more that it reflects their personal values.] Is a country with a higher HDI in a *better* position than a country with a *lower* HDI? That's asking for an opinion.

If you find a notable claim that a measure has some empirical property, we could examine that.

If you find a notable claim that a measure predicts some other measure (i.e. that there is a correlation), we could examine that.